# Como fazer uma função retornar um array em Minizinc

Tags: minizinc

Eu tenho a seguinte função em Minizinc:

```
function var int: DefinitelyVisited(array[int] of var int: S) = forall( i in index_set(S) ) ( S[i] == 1 );
```

Essa função está retornando um inteiro, mas eu preciso que ela retorne um array. Alguém sabe como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

```
function array [int] of int: DefinitelyVisited(array[int] of int: x) =
let {array [int] of int: xx = array1d(x), 
} in (arrayXd(x, [ xx[i] == 1 | i in index_set(xx) ] ) )
```

Essa função retorna um array